# What causes error "'void' type not allowed here" and how do I fix it?

Tags: java

I found error at line LN.Totalbayar= Integer.parseInt(txtTotalBayar.setText(sum+""));
Previously I've tried converting from string to integer. please help

```
private void btnProsesActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    // TODO add your handling code here:        
     ClassProgramTiket LN = new ClassProgramTiket();
     String hrTiket = txtHargaTiket.getText();
    String jmlTiket = txtJumlahTiket.getText();
    int harga = Integer.valueOf(hrTiket);
    int jumlah = Integer.valueOf(jmlTiket);
    int sum = harga * jumlah;    
    LN.Nama=txtNama.getText();
    LN.KodeKereta= (String)cbokodeKereta.getSelectedItem();
    LN.NamaKereta=(String)jenisKereta.getSelectedItem();
    LN.Jurusan= (String)jurusan.getSelectedItem();
    LN.JenisTiket= (String)jenisTiket.getSelectedItem();
    LN.HargaTiket= Integer.parseInt(txtHargaTiket.getText());
    LN.JumlahTiket= Integer.parseInt(txtJumlahTiket.getText());      
    LN.Totalbayar= Integer.parseInt(txtTotalBayar.setText(sum+"")); <- Error 'void' 
type not allowed here
    Tiket.addElement(LN);
     }                
}

//========== class ClassProgramTiket ====  
public class ClassProgramTiket {
public String Nama;
public String KodeKereta;
public String NamaKereta;
public String Jurusan;
public String JenisTiket;
public int HargaTiket;
public int JumlahTiket;
public int Totalbayar;

@Override
public String toString(){     
    return Nama +"-" + KodeKereta +"-" + NamaKereta + "-" + Jurusan +"-" + JenisTiket 
+ "-" + HargaTiket+"-" + JumlahTiket + "-" + Totalbayar;
}
 }
```

Comment: The problem is mostly `txtTotalBayar.setText(sum+"")` returns `void`, not in the `parseInt()` method

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in that line?

Comment: I want to keep the value from sum to field txtTotalBayar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LN.Totalbayar= Integer.parseInt(txtTotalBayar.setText(sum+""));
```

The return type of `setText` is void. `Integer.parseInt` expects a `String`. Setters don't *usually* return anything. Their purpose is to change a value, not retrieve it.

I'm not sure why you are trying to change `txtTotalBayar` while also parsing its value, so it is hard for me to say what the right thing to do is, but perhaps you want something like:

```
txtTotalBayar.setText(sum+"");
LN.Totalbayar= Integer.parseInt(txtTotalBayar.getText());
```